# 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' while trying to input "and" in a list

Tags: list, replace, insert

[Write a program that prints a list with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with 'and' inserted before the last item. The above list would print 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But the program should be able to work with any list not just the one shown above. Because of this, I'll need to use a loop in case the list to print is shorter or longer than the above list. The program should work for all user inputs without "and" or commas if the list only contains one item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4hpU.png)

Comment: Can you also add the language tag in the question

Comment: Can you also explain what do you intend to do ? Specially the line no 5, I don't quite understand what you are trying to do there ?

Comment: Yes, line 5 is if user hits enter with no input then the list should be printed.